# How can I rotate this button 180°?

Tags: css

I am trying to rotate an arrow in a css button but I can't proceed without rotating the whole button...

The point is to make a download button from an upload button. How can I rotate only the arrow?

The button:

```
body {
  background: #2d3e4f;
}
.cntr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.upload {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #e64d43;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.upload:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #c5251a 50%, #2d3e4f 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #c5251a 50%, #2d3e4f 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #c5251a 50%, #2d3e4f 50%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #c5251a 50%, #2d3e4f 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #c5251a 50%, #2d3e4f 50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.upload i {
  width: 2px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 150ms linear;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
}
.upload i:before,
.upload i:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 150ms linear;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
}
.upload i:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-3px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-3px);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-3px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-3px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-3px);
}
.upload i:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(3px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(3px);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(3px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(3px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(3px);
}
.upload:hover i {
  height: 18px;
}
.upload:hover:after {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the actual CSS output instead of a preprocessed one? Not all users are familiar with it, and the issue doesn't lie within an error in the preprocesed CSS.

Comment: Sorry: http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/raqoyb

Answer (score 0):

There are several more efficient ways to do this.

a) Skip all that and use a tool to create an alternate button image with original image rotated 180 degrees.

b) Use one of the NUMEROUS Unicode characters for it instead. See this wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)